# How to configure Default Website in IIS 5.1 through command line script?

Tags: iis, command-line, windows-xp, iis-5

I need to configure IIS 5.1 default website to change the port number, home directory.

Is there any way to configure it without using IIS manager.

Can we do it in command line scripts or can we programmatically achieve it?